# What is the default == behavior for Dart objects?

Tags: dart, comparison, equality

I have the following dart class...

```
class Color {
  final int value;
  const Color._internal(this.value);

  static const Color WHITE = const Color._internal(0);
  static const Color BLACK = const Color._internal(1);

  int get hashCode => value;
  String toString() => (this == WHITE) ? 'W' : 'B';
}
```

I have not implemented the == operator.

What will happen when I use the == operator on two instances of these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will check if the instances **reference** the *same object*.

```dart
Color._internal(0) == Color._internal(0); // false
const Color._internal(0) == const Color._internal(0); // true

final foo = Color._internal(1);
foo == Color._internal(2); // false
foo == Color._internal(1); // false
foo == foo; // true
```

So it will only be true for the same variable (or when passing that reference) **or** for `const` references.

### `Object.==`

The default `==` implementation is `Object.==` because your `Color` class inherently subclasses `Object` (or `Object?` when `null`).

If you take a look at [the `Object.==` implementation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html)), you will see that it is simply:

```dart
external bool operator ==(Object other);
```

Here is a quick summary of how that behaves: the two objects need to be **the exact same object**.

### `identical`

I am pretty sure that the [`identical` fuction](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/identical.html) behaves in exactly the same manner, even though the wording in the documentation is a little bit different:

> Check whether two references are to the same object.

### `hashCode`

Overriding `hashCode` has **no impact** on the default `==` implementation because it will always use [`identityHashCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/identityHashCode.html).

Learn more about [`Object.hashCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html).